# what does these print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8")) mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

```
from subprocess import check_output

print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))
```

the code is from here https://www.kaggle.com/itoeiji/deep-reinforcement-learning-on-stock-data

I know little python,so can't understand what's the purpose of these codes.

Comment: [check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)  | [ls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) | [decode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty clear,

Calling `check_ouput` does the command specified `ls ../input` which list the folder `input` up a directory.

Then it decodes the command result for it to be in utf-8.

And then it prints it for you to see it.

Answer (score 2):

`check_output` runs a shell command and returns its standard output. `decode` decodes a byte string into a proper Python Unicode string.

You [should generally not use `ls` programmatically](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and you should generally avoid using an external subprocess for a task which Python can easily perform itself. A better, more portable and more efficient way to achieve the same result is

```
 import os

 print('\n'.join(os.listdir('../input')))
```

... though this doesn't hard-code the assumption that the file names are returned as UTF-8 (which is probably a good thing for portability, too).

Comment: The code in Kaggle is apparently just a demo, probably on the assumption that even people who are not necessarily familiar with Python have an idea what the Unix `ls` command does.

Comment: This shouldn't be print('\n'.join(os.listdir('../input')))?